# Plotting a histogram for categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataset with two columns like as follows:

```
    index   Year
0   5   <2012
1   8   >=2012
2   9   >=2012
3   10  <2012
4   15  <2012
... ... ...
171 387 >=2012
172 390 <2012
173 398 <2012
174 403 >=2012
175 409 <2012
```

And I would like to plot it in a histogram. I tried with

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')

df.groupby(['Year'])\
      .Year.count().unstack().plot.bar(legend=True)

plt.show()
```

but I have got an error: `AttributeError: 'CategoricalIndex' object has no attribute 'remove_unused_levels'` for

```
df.groupby(['Year'])\
          .Year.count().unstack().plot.bar(legend=True)
```

I think this is because I am using categorical values. Any help would be appreciated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
plt.style.use('ggplot')
df.groupby(["Year"])["Year"].agg("count").plot.bar();
```

[image]

Alternatively:

```
plt.hist(df["Year"]);
```

[image]